# Disable Swagger enum-string-conversions for a particular enum in .NET 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, enums, swagger

I'm generating Open API documentation using Swagger for a .NET 5.0 project. In this project I have several enums that are returned and so I have the project setup to handle these as strings in JSON payloads.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter(new DefaultNamingStrategy {
            OverrideSpecifiedNames = false
        }));
    });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {

        // Set the swagger doc stub
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "API"
        });

        // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
        string xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        string xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

        // Add documentation for our SignalR hubs to the documentation
        c.DocumentFilter<SignalRSwaggerGen.SignalRSwaggerGen>(new List<Assembly> { 
            typeof(NotificationUserHub).Assembly 
        });
    });

    services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
}
```

This works fine for all of my enums. The problem, however, comes when I try to use enums imported from .NET libraries:

```
public sealed class ErrorResponse {

    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

This object uses the `System.Net.HttpStatusCode` enum. When I serialize and deserialize this object, the enum shows up as a numeric value, as intended. However, my Swagger documentation shows the string values for this enum:

[image: Swagger UI showing enum values]

Is there a way to tell swagger that a particular enum should be handled as numerical values?

Comment: I don't think there is, the converter applies to all enumerations.

Comment: @TanveerBadar In that case, is there an attribute that I can add to enums I do want serialized as strings and remove the `services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport()` call?